# How do I run a Java Agent in IBM Domino?

Tags: java, agent, domino-designer-eclipse

I've written a Java Agent in IBM Domino Designer, but I don't know how to run it. Whenever I click "Run Agent" pretty much nothing happens, it only says that

```
Started running agent 'unzipFiles|unzipFiles' on 08.11.2017 10:45:21
Found 0 document(s) that match search criteria
Ran Java Agent Class
Done running agent 'unzipFiles|unzipFiles' on 08.11.2017 10:45:23
```

But when I go directly into the class and click Run As -> Java Applciation everything works fine. What's the problem? It seems to me, that it even doesn't go to the JavaAgent class and invoke main method. I've tried to put Thread.sleep(99999) method, but the time of "execution" of this agent is the same - 2 seconds. How can I solve it?

[The agent properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xMmm.jpg)

Is there any way to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

A Domino agent is not a java application. You don't need to implement the method 'main' but 'NotesMain'. And the agent class must extend lotus.domino.AgentBase.
If you create a new agent from scratch Domino Designer gives you all the boiler plate code. Just start from the line
//Your code goes here

Comment: I actually did it. But there wasn't any result